# Accessing View Data In Model

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to access a variable within charfield entries. Lets say in my views I have...

```
first_name = "John"
last_name = "Smith"
```

In my model I have a list of set greetings, lets say about 20 of them, which I want to randomly pick one and within that entry I want to be able to refer to these variables.

My charfield entries in my models will be something like...

```
Welcome {{first_name}} Im glad you could come back Mr.{{last_name}}
Hello {{first_name}} {{last_name}} welcome back
Hey there {{last_name}}!
etc...
```

So when I want to display one of those entries from my model, it will fill in the first_name,last_name fields from the data's view...

I did try it with template tags but it just gets printed out as a string which I expected it to do so.  I understand this may be confusing.

Or is the best way to just code something that finds the {{first_name}} and replaces it with that value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create string like

```
"Welcome {first_name} Im glad you could come back Mr.{last_name}"
```

Then in view(using python string formatting)

```
Model.field.value.format(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name")
```

Comment: I didnt get the Model.Field part, but the string formatting made sense.  Thanks!